# I'm trying to create a formula for subtracting one value from existing column using trigger using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
create table product
(PROD_CODE varchar(100),
PROD_QOH int);

insert into product 
values("ABC", 1250);

create table part
(PART_CODE varchar(100),
PROD_QOH int);

insert into part
values("A", 567),
("B", 98),
('C', 549);
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Which table should the trigger be on, what do you want to subtract from what?

Comment: How are the `PART_CODE` and `PROD_CODE` related? It looks like they're substrings, which is a horribly inefficient way to relate tables. You should create a real foreign key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.